# Java - How to match event.keycode with colon : slash / backslash \ asterisk * question mark ? double quotes " lessthan < greater than > pipe |

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, keylistener, keyevent, keycode

I am validating Textbox input

```
        name.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 131072) {
                e.doit = false;
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

I can only use  `org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent`  I cannot use any other. I do not wish to match with integer like 131072, is there any constant that is available to match with *e.keycode*. Also I want to match `< > : \ / * " |`.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

For ordinary characters you should use the `character` field of the `KeyEvent`:

```
if (e.character == '<')
```

The `SWT` class contains key code constants for things that are not characters. Such as `SWT.F1`, `SWT.ARROW_UP`, `SWT.HOME`.